# Scala XML Node (with namespace) attributes not accesable

Tags: xml, scala, namespaces

Hiho,

i'm trying to get the attrID from this XML Node/Elem.

```
scala> (desc(0) \ "_")(0)
res81: scala.xml.Node = <cor:attribute cor:attrDataType="int" cor:attrID="singleEventID"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cor="http://rdm.campusonline.at/">883819995</cor:attribute>

scala> (desc(0) \ "_")(0).attributes
res82: scala.xml.MetaData =  cor:attrDataType="int" cor:attrID="singleEventID"

scala> (desc(0) \ "_")(0).attribute("cor:attrID")
res83: Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]] = None

scala> (desc(0) \ "_")(0).attribute("""attrID""")
res85: Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]] = None
```

If i remove the namespace manually, it works just fine.

```
scala> val test4 = <attribute attrDataType="int" attrID="singleEventID" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cor="http://rdm.campusonline.at/">883819995</attribute>
test4: scala.xml.Elem = <attribute attrID="singleEventID" attrDataType="int" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cor="http://rdm.campusonline.at/">883819995</attribute>

scala> test4.attributes
res96: scala.xml.MetaData =  attrID="singleEventID" attrDataType="int"

scala> test4.attribute("attrID")
res98: Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]] = Some(singleEventID)
```

How i can make it work without manually removing the namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the other `attribute` method like this

```
(desc(0) \ "_")(0).attribute("http://rdm.campusonline.at/", "attrID")
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution will give you the attribute as a string

```
val CoreNs = http://rdm.campusonline.at
(desc(0) \ "_") \@ s"{$CoreNs}:attrID"
```